# Will an OrderBy in LINQ maintain the original order as much as possible?

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say that I am doing something like this:

```
new [] { 
    new { a=1, b=true }, new { a=2, b=false }, new { a=3, b=true }, 
    new { a=4, b=false }, new { a=5, b=false } 
}.OrderBy(x => x.b)
```

I have defined an array with integers in ascending order with an associated boolean value.  When I execute this expression in Linqpad, the order of the numbers comes back as `2, 4, 5, 1, 3`.  This is what I would expect to happen; the numbers associated with false values have moved to the top, but otherwise the order has been maintained.

Is this guaranteed to always be true?

Comment: Based on the [OrderBy documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx), it uses a stable sort, which should yield the results you expect as you've described.

Comment: Ah, OK. I just didn't know the correct terminology for what I was asking. Thanks!